# Table Specialization with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

Using mySql, I've created 3 tables: `vehicles`, `cars` and `bikes`.
Tables `cars` and `bikes` are a specialization of the table `vehicles` (child tables).

`vehicles` has one primary key called `id`.

`cars` and `bikes` don't have primary key. Instead they also have a field called `id` with an index on it which contains the same values of `vehicles.id` to act as an foreign key.

[image]

Using Laravel 5.3 framework, I'm trying to, first insert a new record into `vehicles` then insert a new record into `cars` like so:

```
$id = Vehicle::create(['name'=>'volvo'])->id;
Car::create(['id'=>$id, 'nbDoors'=>4]);
```

I get the following error:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `cars` (`nbDorrs`) values (3))

Is there a solution or a better database design so I can insert data in both tables and keep this specialization?

Comment: Does the vehicle create return the id?

Comment: yes it did work fine and return an id.

Comment: Then your car create method does not assign the id field any value.

Comment: Create is a static method that belongs to the inhirited eloquent model from Laravel. It may skip any field named 'id' assuming it is an autoincremented primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
I simply omitted to add id to the fillable columns in the Car model!

```
class Car extends Model
{
  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = ['id', 'nbDoors'];
```